# How can make a user choice for user to chose any movie

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My program is about the user choosing a movie or as many has want to watch from the 7 movies listed and also the price it cost shown. The program will give the user 7 movies to chose from and if they want to chose another the price will add up to the total. So far i have is a array of movies and the price but Im not sure how i should make a user choice for the movies and add the total price. Should i use a switch statement or a loop I'm confused. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MovieHits {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Declare Variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice = 0;
    String [] Movie = new String [7];

    int [] movieCost ={ 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 3}; 

    Movie [0] = "Iron Man";
    Movie [1] = "Transformers";
    Movie [2] = "Godzilla";
    Movie [3] = "Fast and Furious";
    Movie [4] = "Captain America";
    Movie [5] = "X Men";
    Movie [6] = "Rio";

    //Welcome the user
    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to TC Movies OnDemand.");

    //Display the listed movies so the user can know with movie they want to watch
    System.out.println("\nChoose which movie you want to watch: ");
    for ( int index = 0; index < 7; index = index + 1 ) 
    {
        System.out.println(Movie[index]); 
        System.out.println("\t" + "Price: $" + movieCost[index]);
    }

    //Switch Statement to give user a menu to choose a movie
    switch (userChoice)
    {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen.");
        break;
```

Comment: You should use both. A loop allows the user to choose more than just one movie, and the switch can be used to select the wanted movie.

Comment: @vikeng21 i wouldn't mind, possibly with tab completion and regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

You should use loop for printing out the movie selection. After reading the user input you can use switch case to determine which movie was selected. 
Your example code doesn't actually read user input, the instantiated Scanner object is never used. Before switch-case, you should have e.g.

```
userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
```

However, there is a more object oriented "Java way" to do this using Map instead of String arrays, and without switch-case:

```
public class MovieHits {
public static class Movie {
    private int cost;
    private String name;

    public Movie(String name, int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declare Variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice;
    Map<Integer, Movie> movies = new HashMap<Integer, Movie>();
    movies.put(1, new Movie("Iron Man", 5));
    movies.put(2, new Movie("Transformers", 4));
    movies.put(3, new Movie("Godzilla", 3));
    // ...

    //Welcome the user
    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to TC Movies OnDemand.");

    //Display the listed movies so the user can know with movie they want to watch
    System.out.println("\nChoose which movie you want to watch: ");
    Set<Integer> keys = movies.keySet();
    for (Integer key : keys) {
        Movie movie = movies.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + ": " + movie.getName());
        System.out.println("\t" + "Price: $" + movie.getCost());
    }
    userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have chosen " + movies.get(userChoice).getName());
```

Inner classes are usually against best practice, but in this case I used it to keep it simple.

If user can select multiple movies, then read userChoice inside a while-loop and break it with a certain number or if user inputs empty line. Inside the loop store the selected movies e.g. in a List, calculate total price for user to see inside the loop, or after all wanted movies are selected.